# joins in sql, error ORA-01722:invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

Write query to display user_id and user name of those who have canceled their tickets and display records in ascending order by user_id

```
select user_id,
(select name 
from users u 
where u.user_id=
   (select t.ticket_id 
    from tickets t 
    where t.user_id=
        (select c.cancellation_id 
         from cancellation c
         where t.ticket_id=c.ticket_id 
         and c.cancellation_id>0
   ))) as name 
from users u
```

[here is the image]

[image: 1]

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and the table formats.  No one but you really knows what columns are numbers and which are not.

Comment: My guess is the problem is with `c.cancellation_id > 0`, because c.cancellation_id is a string.

Comment: @GordonLinoff edited as per requirement

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I have removed this line to check whether it's creating problem but still showing same error

Comment: Also just noticed `user_id` is a number, while both `ticket_id` and `cancellation_id` are strings. Logically speaking, why should a user_id match a ticket_id or a cancellation_id anyway? They seem like different things.

Comment: You have an unbalanced number of braces. You have 2 select statements at the beginning. If you fix these issues then your SQL will technically be correct but obviously wont return the data you expect, given the issues pointed out by @WilliamRobertson

Comment: @WilliamRobertson can you please write a code i not able to correct this

Comment: You need a join of users, tickets and cancellation. Join on columns with the same name (user_id to user_id, ticket_id to ticket_id).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson that's fine but i wises to do with the help of subquery

Comment: OK, so query users where user_id in (join of tickets and cancellations).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I am not getting your point, can you write the whole query

Comment: @NickW I have corrected it please check it

Comment: @WilliamRobertson                                                                                                     select user_id,
(select u.name 
from users u 
where u.user_id=
   (select t.user_id 
    from tickets t 
    where t.ticket_id=
        (select c.cancellation_id 
         from cancellation c
         where t.ticket_id=c.ticket_id 
         and c.cancellation_id is not null
   ))) as name 
from users u

Comment: You are still trying to match `ticket_id` to `cancellation_id`, which cannot be right. And surely you are allowed to use joins and not just subqueries? See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need users where a cancelled ticket exists:

```
select user_id, user_name
from   users u
where  u.user_id in
       ( select t.user_id
         from   tickets t
                join cancellation c
                     on c.ticket_id = t.ticket_id );
```

which for my test data (see below) gives:

```
USER_ID USER_NAME
------- --------------------
      1 Dave
      5 Mick
```

For SQL questions it helps a lot if you provide the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements to recreate the issue. For example:

```
create table users
( user_id number(11) primary key
, user_name varchar2(20) );

create table tickets
( ticket_id varchar2(3) primary key
, user_id references users );

create table cancellation  -- why not cancellations, by the way?
( cancellation_id varchar2(3) primary key
, ticket_id references tickets );

insert all
    into users values (1, 'Dave')
    into users values (2, 'Dee')
    into users values (3, 'Dozy')
    into users values (4, 'Beaky')
    into users values (5, 'Mick')
    into users values (6, 'Titch')
    into tickets values ('TK1', 1)
    into tickets values ('TK2', 1)
    into tickets values ('TK3', 2)
    into tickets values ('TK4', 2)
    into tickets values ('TK5', 3)
    into tickets values ('TK6', 5)
    into cancellation values ('CA1', 'TK1')
    into cancellation values ('CA2', 'TK2')
    into cancellation values ('CA3', 'TK6')
select * from dual;
```

Working example at [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a05cf45b16db1ce99c1e80f1eb3add61).

Other ways to explore the data:

```
select u.user_id, u.user_name, c.ticket_id, c.cancellation_id
from   users u
       join tickets t on t.user_id = u.user_id
       join cancellation c on c.ticket_id = t.ticket_id;

USER_ID USER_NAME            TICKET_ID CANCELLATION_ID
------- -------------------- --------- ---------------
      1 Dave                 TK1       CA1
      1 Dave                 TK2       CA2
      5 Mick                 TK6       CA3
```

```
select u.user_id, u.user_name, count(*)
from   users u
       join tickets t on t.user_id = u.user_id
       join cancellation c on c.ticket_id = t.ticket_id
group by u.user_id, u.user_name;

USER_ID USER_NAME              COUNT(*)
------- -------------------- ----------
      1 Dave                          2
      5 Mick                          1
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the error in my program. Here is the query using purely inner query

```
select u.user_id,u.name from users u where u.user_id
in (select t.user_id from tickets t where t.ticket_id 
in (select c.ticket_id from cancellation c where 
cancellation_id is not null));
```